# Need result for the MySQL joins for this method

Tags: mysql, join

I have two table one is *order_details* and second is *orders*.

1) order_details

```
id  |  order_id     |     item     |   order_units   |   is_cancelled |
------------------------------------------------------------------
1   |     00001     |   Mobile     |    2            |      0         |
2   |     00001     |   Headphone  |    2            |      0         |
3   |     00001     |   cover      |    5            |      0         |
4   |     00002     |   charger    |    1            |      0         |
5   |     00002     |   mobile     |    1            |      0         |
6   |     00004     |   Tablet     |    2            |      0         |
7   |     00005     |   Mobile     |    1            |      0         |
8   |     00005     |   Battery    |    2            |      1         |
9   |     00006     |   Mobile     |    1            |      0         |
10  |     00006     |   speaker    |    1            |      0         |
11  |     00006     |   Motinor    |    1            |      0         |
12  |     00007     |   Laptop     |    2            |      0         |
```

2) orders

```
order_id |    date      |  time   |total_amount| round |discount|refund 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
00001    | 2017-06-16   |10:10:45 | 456.12     |-0.12  | 0      | 0 
00002    | 2017-06-16   |10:25:45 | 600.00     | 0.00  | 10     | 50
00004    | 2017-06-16   |11:10:45 | 300.55     |-0.05  | 0      | 0
00005    | 2017-06-16   |12:10:45 | 200.45     | 0.05  | 20     | 0
00006    | 2017-06-16   |12:40:45 | 685.00     | 0.00  | 50     | 0
00007    | 2017-06-24   |14:10:45 | 888.35     | 0.15  | 0      | 0
```

I want to join the "order_details" with "orders" and the result should be as below:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------
     date      | time    | hour |order_count| total_units| net_amount
---------------------------------------------------------------------
| 2017-06-16   |10:10:45 | 10   |    2      |  11       | 996
| 2017-06-16   |11:10:45 | 11   |    1      |   2       | 300.50
| 2017-06-16   |12:40:45 | 12   |    2      |   4       | 180.50
--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I have created a sql query for the above result format and all columns outputs are correct except the "total_units", its showing null.
The following query i have used:

```
SELECT hdr.date,hdr.time, LPAD(HOUR(hdr.time),2,'0') AS hour, COUNT(hdr.`order_id`) AS order_count, dtl.total_units, SUM((hdr.total_amount+hdr.round-hdr.discount)-hdr.refund) AS net_amount
FROM orders hdr
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT order_id, SUM(qty) AS total_units
FROM order_details
WHERE is_cancelled=0) dtl ON dtl.order_id = hdr.order_id
WHERE DATE(hdr.date) = '2017-06-16 ' AND (HOUR(hdr.time) BETWEEN ('10') AND ('12'))
GROUP BY hdr.date, HOUR(hdr.time)
```

Please help me to correct this query and generate the exact output as above.

Comment: in your sub query (dtl) you have SUM(qty). qty doesnt exist in your order_details table

Comment: Where is it getting qty in SUM(qty) AS total_units, should it be order_units?

Comment: Sorry, qty is order_units... it is sum(order_units) AS total_units

Comment: Not all of them are null - you need a group by order_id in the sub query.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, One correction in my query..

```
SELECT hdr.date,hdr.time, LPAD(HOUR(hdr.time),2,'0') AS hour, COUNT(hdr.`order_id`) AS order_count, dtl.total_units, SUM((hdr.total_amount+hdr.round-hdr.discount)-hdr.refund) AS net_amount
FROM orders hdr
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT order_id, SUM(order_units) AS total_units
FROM order_details
WHERE is_cancelled=0) dtl ON dtl.order_id = hdr.order_id
WHERE DATE(hdr.date) = '2017-06-16 ' AND (HOUR(hdr.time) BETWEEN ('10') AND ('12'))
GROUP BY hdr.date, HOUR(hdr.time)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have made some corrections in the query and it is working fine now:

```
SELECT hdr.date,hdr.time, LPAD(HOUR(hdr.time),2,'0') AS hour, COUNT(hdr.`order_id`) AS order_count, SUM(dtl.order_units) AS total_units, SUM((hdr.total_amount+hdr.round-hdr.discount)-hdr.refund) AS net_amount
FROM orders hdr
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT order_id, SUM(order_units) AS order_units
FROM order_details
WHERE is_cancelled=0 GROUP BY order_id) dtl ON dtl.order_id = hdr.order_id
WHERE DATE(hdr.date) = '2017-06-16 ' AND (HOUR(hdr.time) BETWEEN ('10') AND ('12'))
GROUP BY hdr.date, HOUR(hdr.time)
```

Thank you.